# ¿Por qué no me guarda los cambios en la base de datos?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy editando los datos de un usuario en mi sistema, pero al momento de tratar de modificar su perfil estos cambios no son guardados en la base de datos siendo que uso en procedimiento similar en otro controlador.

Este es el action que uso para editar al usuario en el controlador

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Editar(Usuario usuario, FormCollection form, string Rol)
    {
        var objEdit = db.Usuario.Where(x => x.Vigente == true && x.IdUsuario == usuario.IdUsuario).FirstOrDefault();

       
        if (objEdit != null)
        {
            objEdit.Nombre = usuario.Nombre;
            objEdit.Correo = usuario.Correo;
            objEdit.Rut = usuario.Rut;
            objEdit.IdEmpresa = 1;
            objEdit.FechaCreacion = objEdit.FechaCreacion;
            objEdit.UltimoLogin = objEdit.UltimoLogin;
            objEdit.IdBloqueo = 1;
            objEdit.Token = null;
            objEdit.Vigente = true;
            

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(usuario.Clave))
            {
                objEdit.Clave = CryproHelper.ComputeHash(usuario.Clave, CryproHelper.Supported_HA.SHA512, null);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
      
            Usuario.UpdatePerfilUsuario(usuario.IdUsuario, Rol);//aqui llamo al metodo de la clase

            if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)//aqui valido si ha sido guardado los cambios del peril del usuario
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Se ha guardado");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No guardo");
            }


                return Json(new Response() { IsSuccess = true, Message = "Se ha editado el usuario correctamente!." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(new Response() { IsSuccess = false, Message = "No se pudo editar al usuario" });
    }
```

Y este es el método que uso para editar el perfil del usuario en una clase donde valido que el usuario este vigente y donde solo modifico su idPerfil para verificar su rol en el sistema, pero estos cambios no son guardados

```
  public UsuarioPerfil UpdatePerfilUsuario(int id, string rol)
    {
        var existe = db.UsuarioPerfil.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdUsuario == id);
        return existe ?? new UsuarioPerfil()
        {
            IdUsuario = id,
            IdPerfil = Convert.ToInt32(rol),
            Activo = true,
            Vigente = true

        };
       

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, es difícil saber lo que estás haciendo porque te sales del estándar de cómo se hacen realmente las cosas.

¿Como se realiza un update con ASP MVC y EF?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Editar(Usuario usuario)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) { // Si tienes validaciones, pues validamos que los campos ingresados son correctos
         //Aquí devolvemos que los datos ingresados no son correctos
    }

    if(!db.Usuario.Any(x => x.Vigente == true && x.IdUsuario == usuario.IdUsuario)){
        //Quieres validar que el usuario que se está editando existe y que además está vigente, usas Any
        //Retornamos algo avisando que el usuario no existe
    }

    //esto ni idea porque lo haces, pero supongo que importa
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(usuario.Clave))
    {
        usuario.Clave = CryproHelper.ComputeHash(usuario.Clave, CryproHelper.Supported_HA.SHA512, null);
    }
    try{
        db.Update(usuario);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch{
       //return algun error
    }
   
    //retornamos que ha sido guardado correctamente
}
```

Si te fijas el objEdit no tiene sentido.

También debo hacer notar que hacer el update son solo 2 líneas de códigos, el resto son validaciones.

Por otro lado y fuera del tema, recomiendo que leas esta [publicación](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/conventions-in-ef-core.aspx), ya que los nombres de tus propiedades los pusiste al revés, por ejemplo IdEmpresa debería ser EmpresaId, esto NO es un error pero ayuda a realizar menos configuraciones posteriores